# Integral of $\int\limits_0^L {{x^{2k}}{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx} $

Tags: integration

I'm looking for solution for this integral. I've tried many time but I can't

$\int\limits_0^L {{x^{2k}}{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx} $

So anyone is willing to help me? Thank for your help

Comment: your integral containes the Gamma function

Comment: What is the original problem? Why do you need to compute such non-elementary integral (the case $k=0$ should be well-known...)?

Comment: Thank for your advice. Actually, i found the formula for my research, it related to issue of distance on 2D Poisson process in the circle. The probability density function of distance from any point to _n_ th neighbor is $f(x) = \frac{{2{{(\pi \lambda )}^s}}}{{(s - 1)!}}{x^{2s - 1}}{e^{ - \pi \lambda {x^2}}}$. So i'd like calculate the expected value of _x_

Answer (score 0):

This kind of integral may not compute its value directly, but we can express it by lower incomplete Gamma's function with a change of variable $x^2=t$.

See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) if you do not know the lower incomplete Gamma's function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x^2=y\implies x=\sqrt y\implies dx=\frac{dy}{2 \sqrt{y}}$$ which make $$I=\int {{x^{2k}}{e^{ - {x^2}}}\,dx}=\frac{1}{2} \int y^{k-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-y}\,dy=-\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2},y\right)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: I very thank you, but do you have any suggestion about the bounds of the integral?